# Выдаёт ошибку при попытке обратиться к API

Tags: python, dialogflow

Выдаёт ошибку при попытке обратиться к API - {'status': {'code': 400, 'errorType': 'bad_request', 'errorDetails': 'Either query or event name is required. Code: 400'}}

```
import apiai
import json

def agent_TODD(message):
    request = apiai.ApiAI('efd201714e6e48f690cb9ea5c7d73c9d').text_request() #token Api k dialogflow
    request.lang = 'ru' #на каком языке будет написан запрос
    request.session_id = 'session_1' #id sessii nuzhno chto by potom obuchat bota
    request.querry = message
    response = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(response)
agent_TODD(input())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил `request.querry = message` на `request.query = message`, была обнаружена ошибка в слове.

**Правильный вариант программы:**

```
import apiai
import json


def agent_TODD(message):
    request = apiai.ApiAI('efd201714e6e48f690cb9ea5c7d73c9d').text_request()  # token Api k dialogflow
    request.lang = 'ru'  # на каком языке будет написан запрос
    request.session_id = 'session_1'  # id sessii nuzhno chto by potom obuchat bota
    request.query = message
    response = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
    print(response)


agent_TODD(input())
```